# SQL select fields containing uppercase characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a simple SQL Server 2008 update query using `LOWER(FIELD_NAME)` that should only update where `FIELD_NAME` contains uppercase characters.

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET FIELD_NAME = LOWER(FIELD_NAME)
WHERE FIELD_NAME *contains uppercase characters*
```

How can I select only columns with uppercase characters in the where clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a case-sensitive collation:

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET FIELD_NAME = LOWER(FIELD_NAME)
WHERE FIELD_NAME LIKE '%[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXZ]%' COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CS_AS
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following out:

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET FIELD_NAME = LOWER(FIELD_NAME)
WHERE FIELD_NAME LIKE '%[A-Z]%' Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

If you also have other characters such as numbers then the you could also do the query as follows:

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET FIELD_NAME = LOWER(FIELD_NAME)
WHERE FIELD_NAME = UPPER(FIELD_NAME) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

Comment: `'%[A-Z]%'` is incorrect. [A-Z] means [AaBbCc..YyZ] in SQL server. You can try `'z'` which is not LIKE `'%[A-Z]%'`

Comment: @Eric The "CS" in the collation statement above means Case Sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @table table (val varchar(10))
insert into @table(val) values ('MOHAN'),('rohan')

update @table set val = LOWER(val) where val = UPPER(val) OR VAL LIKE '%[A-Z]%'COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS

select * from @table
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method:

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET FIELD_NAME=LOWER(FIELD_NAME)
WHERE FIELD_NAME!=LOWER(FIELD_NAME) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI
```

[Reference](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic800271-338-1.aspx)

Comment: copy some code snippet from link to avoid link inactive in fututre